# Validate embedded document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, validation

I'd like to validate my documents in MongoDB. As described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/), the validator query can be specified during the `createCollection` command.

My application is a simple todo list, so the collection `list` has many documents like this:

```
{
   "name": "the list name",
   "color: "red",
   "items": [
     {
       "title": "item1",
       "isDone": false,
       "text": "the item description"
     }
   ]
}
```

How can I sure that all documents has this shape?

**EDIT:** I'm using MongoDB 3.4

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

There's no way to avoid new property. If this needed is required, you should consider to migrate a SQL solution.

Otherwise, your document will contain at least those members and those members will be validated.

I assume that all fields are mandatory, so no list can be added neither without a color nor having an item without a title.

I assume that color is an enum also.

```
{
  validator: {
    name: { $type: 'string', $exists: true },
    color: { $in: ['red', 'green', 'blue'], $exists: true },
    items: { $exists: true },
    $or: [
      { items: { $size: 0 } },
      {
        $and: [
          { 'items.0': { $exists: true } },
          {
            items: {
              $not: {
                $elemMatch: {
                  $not: { $type: 'object' }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            items: {
              $not: {
                $elemMatch: {
                  $or: [
                    { title: { $not: { $type: 'string' } } },
                    { title: { $not: { $exists: true } } },
                    { isDone: { $not: { $type: 'bool' } } },
                    { isDone: { $not: { $exists: true } } },
                    { text: { $not: { $type: 'string' } } },
                    { text: { $not: { $exists: true } } }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

***Explanation***

The solution is based on the [second-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic).
Indeed, the assertion "all elements have to match A" is equal to "no element should match !A" or, if you have many queries, "all element have to match A and B" becomes "no element should match !A or !B", where `!` means the negation of the following predicate.

***Long explanation***

The first two query items assert that all documents have `name` and `color`, the third one the `items` property always exists.
NB: in the third query property, there's not the `$type` check because mongodb treats the `array` type [in a odd way](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#arrays).

The `$or` operation below is needed because the `item` property can be empty or filled with some data.

First clause of `$or` checks if the array is empty.
If the array is not empty, three checks should be done:

- the array contains at least one element
- the array has to contain only object
- all object has a specified shape.

So the first `$and` operator element checks that at least one element is present. The second one checks that all array elements are objects. The third one asserts that all objects have a specified shape.

In mongodb, there's an operator for checking if all array elements match a query. So, using the second order logic, the check should be turned over.

In fact, the last two clauses of `$and` check that no elements match none of the described query. Each sub query is the negate of a wanted query.

***Example***

*fails*

```
{ name: 'foo' }
{ color: 'red' }
{ color: 'unknown color' }
{ name: 'foo', color: 'red' }
{ name: 'foo', color: 'red', item: 3 }
{ name: 'foo', color: 'red', item: [ 3 ] }
{ name: 'foo', color: 'red', item: [ { } ] }
{ name: 'foo', color: 'red', item: [ { title: 'ww' } ] }
{ name: 'foo', color: 'red', item: [ { title: 'ww', isDone: false } ] }
{ name: 'foo', color: 'red', item: [ { title: 44, isDone: false, text: 'the text' } ] }
```

*pass*

```
    { name: 'foo', color: 'red', items: [ ] },
    { name: 'foo', color: 'red', items: [ ] },
    { name: 'foo', color: 'red', items: [ { title: 'the title', isDone: false, text: 'the text' }, { title: 'the title1', isDone: true, text: 'the text' } ] }
```

This solution is still valid using MongoDB 3.2